# getting error in CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO and PIX_FMT_YUV420P

Tags: java, android, javacv

I am trying to create a code which will convert images into video. I have surfed a lot and find some method to do it using javacv. now i am getting variable not found error in these lines.

```
recorder.setCodecID( CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
recorder.setPixelFormat(  PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
```

I have imported all the jar files into my library as well but still getting this error. Some quick help would be appreciated. I have gone through the below link for the importing the javacv into my workspace.

[How to Import JavaCV libraries to Android Project](http://javacv4android.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-import-javacv-libraries-to.html)

```
package com.example.photoaday;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvShowImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvWaitKey;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_GAUSSIAN;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvSmooth;

import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Recordvideo extends Activity {

//  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create);
    opencv_core.IplImage img = cvLoadImage("/sdcard/folder/img1.jpg");
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/sdcard/folder/test.mpeg",200,150);
    try {
        recorder.setCodecID( CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
        recorder.setFrameRate(30);
        recorder.setPixelFormat(  PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        recorder.start();

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
           recorder.record(img);
        }
        recorder.stop();
     }
     catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}


}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: The below is the full code

Answer (score -1):

I assume that your compiler gives error as follows

error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘PIX_FMT_YUV420P’ was not declared in this scope

then solution for error is

change : ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ to 'AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO'

change : ‘PIX_FMT_YUV420P’ to 'AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P'